# How to get all the rows when executing query in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have question in codeigniter.

1. Get All the  rows when Executing the Query

In CI I want to get all the rows when I am executing the query like

```
Select * from tablename
```

But when I am using the

```
return $query->row();
```

I am getting only one row.How can I get all the rows.I  dont get any idea in [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of this

```
$query->row();
```

use this

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->field_name;
    //use the database table fields name in the place of field_name property
}
```

Comment: hey dude the title is an example use the field name of your table instead

Comment: Oh Sorry I am a newguy to CI.Thax a lot